# future completing but not terminating unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, dart

So I am trying to unit test a future and when the future returns complete the editor still says the tests are running. I am not sure what I am missing here.

```dart
User user = new User(access);

test('DataObject Get Test', () {
  print('user getting');
  Future future = user.Get('4460A611-7682-4552-A086-1DFDC8E4CB9D');
  expect(future, completion(equals(user)));
});
```

Output:

```
unittest-suite-wait-for-done
user getting
PASS: DataObject Get Test

All 1 tests passed.
unittest-suite-success
```

After the `unittest-suite-success` the editor just sits there acting like the tests aren't done. The pause and stop buttons are still active and the Debugger window still has an isolate in it.

Comment: What does your User class look like? Does it create a timer?

Comment: It does not. I just resigned myself to the fact that this happens. Its not worth it to me to figure out why. It doesn't hurt functionality in any other way.